# Can differennt computation model lead to different complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory, computer-architecture, computation-models

There are many examples where someone replaces a CPU with a GPU or an FPGA and get a performance boost of $\times 100$ or more, but is it possible for a change in the architecture of computational resource to reduce the least possible complexity of solving a problem, say, from $\Theta(n^2)$ to $\Theta(n)$?

Basically, I'm looking for an example like [Bead sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bead_sort).